# Swift Build fail with "Error Unknown class name 'FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate'"

Tags: ios, swift, unity-game-engine, fbsdk, fbsdkloginkit

I'm building an app with Facebook login and Unity-Swift integration. When I build the app in Xcode, I got a **Semantic Issue** and **Generics Issues** in DemoApp-Swift.h file. Error said `FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate` is unknown class. See my codes:

**LoginViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKShareKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import Firebase
import Toast_Swift
import TRON
import CoreData

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate{


    let loginButton : FBSDKLoginButton = {
        let button = FBSDKLoginButton()
        button.readPermissions=["email"]
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(loginButton)
        //            //frame's are obselete, please use constraints instead because its 2016 after all
        loginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 110, y: 300, width: view.frame.width - 200, height: 30)

        if (FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil ){
           //some code
        }
        loginButton.delegate = self
    }



    func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
        print("User Logged Out")

    }

    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {

        self.view.makeToastActivity(.center)

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
        if result.isCancelled {
            return
        }
        if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
        {

        }

    }
}
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKShareKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import Firebase
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    var application: UIApplication?

    @objc var currentUnityController: UnityAppController!

    var isUnityRunning = false

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()

        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.rootViewController = LoginViewController()
        self.application = application
        unity_init(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
        currentUnityController = UnityAppController()

        currentUnityController.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
        startUnity()
        stopUnity()
         window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }

    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

        let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String!, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

        return handled
    }
//some unity codes
}
```

**Bridging-header.h**

```
#ifndef BRIDGING_HEADER
#define BRIDGING_HEADER

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "UnityUtils.h"
#import "UnityAppController.h"
#import "UnityInterface.h"

#endif /* BRIDGING_HEADER */
```

I spend more time to fix it, but I can't figure it out. I can fix this with Xcode compiler suggestions, but when I build Archive file it always fail with same issues.

Please help me.

[image: Issues on DemoApp-swift.h]

Comment: please do `pod update` ..

Comment: @vaibhav I tried with `pod update`  but it was not fixed